# android Fragment re-creation after onDestroy - FragmentManagerState ClassNotFound

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-ondestroy

I'm working on an activity with a viewpager with 3 fragments.

After starting a pick image intent onactivityResult is called but
the starter activity is destroyed & created again.

> (I've turned on Don't keep any activities,Developer settings.)

Now the problem is after activity is created fragments are also created again
(Observed via Log)

This appears in Log after activity recreated.

```
 E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
```

The onActivity result is programatically forwarded to fragment via `Activity>getsViewpager>getsAdapter>getsFragment` methods.

but now `getContext()` in fragment returns null.
(Which means new fragments are created but `onactivityResult` passes to old fragment?)
What i expect is either the old fragments should be reattached or the `onActivityResult` passed to new fragments.

How can i distinguish new/old  activity/fragments?
How can i simply restore fragments after activity recreated?
What is the problem causing Class not found when unmarshalling error.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this yet?

Comment: I didn't solve it but was successful to bypass it by cleaning the code.It was probably the result of messy code. Unfortunately I don't exactly remember what i did